# How do I handle errors in a worker pool using WaitGroup?

Tags: go, wait, channel, coroutine

I got a problem using `sync.WaitGroup` and `select` together. If you take a look at following http request pool you will notice that if an error occurs it will never be reported as `wg.Done()` will block and there is no read from the channel anymore.

```
package pool

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var (
    MaxPoolQueue  = 100
    MaxPoolWorker = 10
)

type Pool struct {
    wg *sync.WaitGroup

    queue  chan *http.Request
    errors chan error
}

func NewPool() *Pool {
    return &Pool{
        wg: &sync.WaitGroup{},

        queue:  make(chan *http.Request, MaxPoolQueue),
        errors: make(chan error),
    }
}

func (p *Pool) Add(r *http.Request) {
    p.wg.Add(1)

    p.queue <- r
}

func (p *Pool) Run() error {
    for i := 0; i < MaxPoolWorker; i++ {
        go p.doWork()
    }

    select {
    case err := <-p.errors:
        return err
    default:
        p.wg.Wait()
    }

    return nil
}

func (p *Pool) doWork() {
    for r := range p.queue {
        fmt.Printf("Request to %s\n", r.Host)

        p.wg.Done()

        _, err := http.DefaultClient.Do(r)

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)

            p.errors <- err
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("no error\n")
        }
    }
}
```

Source can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/bodokaiser/4635e800f26c68d37da5)

**How can I still use WaitGroup but also get errors from go routines?**

Comment: You could use [golang.org/x/sync/errgroup](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup?tab=doc#example-Group-Parallel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just got the answer my self as I wrote the question and as I think it is an interesting case I would like to share it with you.

The trick to use `sync.WaitGroup` and `chan` together is that we wrap:

```
select {
    case err := <-p.errors:
        return err
    default:
        p.wg.Done()
}
```

Together in a `for` loop:

```
for {
    select {
        case err := <-p.errors:
            return err
        default:
            p.wg.Done()
    }
}
```

In this case select will always check for errors and wait if nothing happens :)

Comment: Common - They give you the opportunity to answer your own question and then you need to wait two days...

Comment: I'd like to point out that Go 1.3 already includes [sync.Pool](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Pool).

Comment: @OneOfOne I use sync.Pool to store responses. But I think it makes sense to store an anon struct with request, response and error in the pool. Makes life easier :)

Answer (score 4):

It looks a bit like the fail-fast mechanism enabled by the [Tomb library](https://github.com/go-tomb/tomb/tree/v2) ([Tomb V2 GoDoc](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/tomb.v2)):

> The tomb package handles clean goroutine tracking and termination.
>
> If any of the tracked goroutines returns a non-nil error, or the `Kill` or `Killf` method is called by any goroutine in the system (tracked or not), the tomb `Err` is set, `Alive` is set to `false`, and the `Dying` channel is closed to flag that all tracked goroutines are supposed to willingly terminate as soon as possible.
>
> Once all tracked goroutines terminate, the `Dead` channel is closed, and `Wait` unblocks and returns the first non-nil error presented to the tomb via a result or an explicit `Kill` or `Killf` method call, or nil if there were no errors.

You can see an example [in this playground](http://play.golang.org/p/K-4PEvWy-W):

(extract)

```
// start runs all the given functions concurrently
// until either they all complete or one returns an
// error, in which case it returns that error.
//
// The functions are passed a channel which will be closed
// when the function should stop.
func start(funcs []func(stop <-chan struct{}) error) error {
    var tomb tomb.Tomb
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    allDone := make(chan struct{})
    // Start all the functions.
    for _, f := range funcs {
        f := f
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            if err := f(tomb.Dying()); err != nil {
                tomb.Kill(err)
            }
        }()
    }
    // Start a goroutine to wait for them all to finish.
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(allDone)
    }()

    // Wait for them all to finish, or one to fail
    select {
    case <-allDone:
    case <-tomb.Dying():
    }
    tomb.Done()
    return tomb.Err()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler implementation would be like below. (Check in play.golang: https://play.golang.org/p/TYxxsDRt5Wu)

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "sync"
import "time"

type Error struct {
    message string
}

func (e Error) Error() string {
    return e.message
}

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    waitGroupLength := 8
    errChannel := make(chan error, 1)

    // Setup waitgroup to match the number of go routines we'll launch off
    wg.Add(waitGroupLength)
    finished := make(chan bool, 1) // this along with wg.Wait() are why the error handling works and doesn't deadlock

    for i := 0; i < waitGroupLength; i++ {

        go func(i int) {
            fmt.Printf("Go routine %d executed\n", i+1)
            time.Sleep(time.Duration(waitGroupLength - i))
            time.Sleep(0) // only here so the time import is needed
            
            if i%4 == 1 {
                errChannel <- Error{fmt.Sprintf("Errored on routine %d", i+1)}
            }
            
            // Mark the wait group as Done so it does not hang
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(finished)
    }()

    L:
        for {
            select {
            case <-finished:
                break L // this will break from loop
            case err := <-errChannel:
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println("error ", err)
                    // handle your error
                }
            }
        }

    fmt.Println("Executed all go routines")
}
```